# Trying to queuing up multiple files in pygame.music

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

I'm trying to get a queue of music files in random order for playing on a raspberry pi using pygame. But I'm finding an issue (limitation?) of where it seems to be only able to queue up song.

I've tried to reproduce it on my desktop (so I can debug it) but the queuing doesn't seem to work at all on it. It can't even queue up 1 other file. Hence, I'm wondering why it won't even work on my desktop. I've stripped down my desktop testing/debugging code to as follows:

```
import pygame
import random
import time

soundType = ".ogg"
# files are in the same directory at the moment
musicLocation = ""
musicFiles = (("takepills01", 0), ("takepistol01", 0), ("takesniper01", 0), ("taunt01", 0), ("teamkillaccident02", 0), ("thanks01", 0))

queuedFilesResut = []

pygame.mixer.init()

# choose a random file to start
selectedMusicName = musicFiles[random.randint(0, len(musicFiles) - 1)][0]
pygame.mixer.music.load(musicLocation + selectedMusicName + soundType)
queuedFilesResut.append(selectedMusicName)

# choose a random file to follow
selectedMusicName = musicFiles[random.randint(0, len(musicFiles) - 1)][0]
pygame.mixer.music.play()
pygame.mixer.music.queue(musicLocation + selectedMusicName + soundType)
queuedFilesResut.append(selectedMusicName)

# not sure if it matters if the play() call is before or after the queue() call
# seen it both ways on a few examples
#pygame.mixer.music.play()

# print to see what was selected
print queuedFilesResut

# now sleep for a bit while the music plays, the testing files are very short, each only 1-2 seconds
time.sleep(5)
```

What happens right now for the above code is that whatever file is selected first plays, then that's it. Here is how I was attempting to queue up multiple files, before I realised I couldn't even queue up 1 file:

```
for counter in range(0, 10):
    selectedMusicName = musicFiles[random.randint(0, len(musicFiles) - 1)][0]
    pygame.mixer.music.queue(musicLocation + selectedMusicName + soundType)
    queuedFilesResut.append(selectedMusicName)
```

I was really expecting pygame to be able to just play a song and queue up 'n' files, then I could just forget about it and leave it run its course.

---

Although this is just a question more on why the above script doesn't work, I should add that when I go back to the raspberry pi, I'm calling the music playing python script via lighttpd and thus need the method call to return to be responsive -I don't think I can use a loop to check for when the music is done playing/check the event queue. Lighttpd also seems to limit python to just 1 thread.

I do have an idea on how to get around this whole issue/limitation, but it involves running a loop as an entirely separate python process on startup and having a written file to communicate between lighttpd-python and python. I am hoping to find a nicer/cleaner way.

Comment: Just to help, instead of doing a large `random.randint()`, try random.choice. Or just do `random.randint(1,5)`, and for each number, assign a song.

Comment: oh, neat. I did not know about random.choice for pulling random elements out of a list. It doesn't solve the problem, but still helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I know this was in 2014 and was with python 2.7 but this could be useful to others with this problem.

I am using python 3.4.

You could try to put your randomly chosen files in a list and play the list like a playlist. The songs will play from left to right in the list.

E.g.

```
for file in musicList:
    #play song here
    time.sleep(5)
```

You can add files to this list mid program by using:

```
#Chosen random music file
songList.append(musicFile)
```

Hope this helps.
Cheers